# How do we remove the inline code listener?

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose we have added listener to a changeNotifier object in a view like following:

```
someChangeNotifierObject.addListener((){ if (this.mounted) setState(){}});
```

1. Do we need to remove the listener explicitly when the view is getting disposed?
2. What would be the impact if not removing it?
3. How to remove it since it is an inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you add a listener to a super object (an object located outside of current state) and you use setState inside of the listener - in that case you **should** remove it explicitly on current state dispose.
2. Otherwise, setState will throw an exception when the object notifies its listeners, as the state inside of which you added a listener would have been disposed to that moment.
3. Do not use inline functions in `addListener`. If you need `mounted` - it can be accessed anywhere throughout the `State`, except for static methods. Hence, simply create a new function inside of the current State class.

e.g.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  someChangeNotifierObject.addListener(myListenerFunc);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  someChangeNotifierObject.removeListener(myListenerFunc);
  super.dispose();
}

void myListenerFunc() {
  print("Heya the object has changed!");
  setState(() {
    // re-render current stateful widget.
  });
}
```

However, it is simply a good practice to remove listeners on dispose - no matter whether you use `State`'s methods inside of a listener or not.